# CPU speed stuck at 798 MHz

Tags: cpu

I am quite new to Ubuntu and Linux world, Can anyone help me to increase the normal CPU speed of my processor? It is a i5 2.3 GHz and for some odd reason is stuck at 798 MHz, that's why I installed linux and stopped using OS X, Ubuntu feels faster but is still not using my processor at its normal speed. I tried different distro to increase the governor performance but even on Performance mode clock speed still at 798 MHz. Can any one help me through this issue? Can it be done from BIOS?

Comment: I think you're confusing FSB (front-side bus) speeds with backside speeds. 800Mhz is the speed at which the cpu speaks on the FSB or any device connected to it that way, 2.3GHz will be the speed at which the cpu can speak to cache etc.  Marketing/Sales literature of course only talks about the faster clock speed...   We only support Ubuntu and official flavors here, and your question really is a hardware one.

Comment: @guiverc This is a legit question. There are many hardware questions about how to run an official flavor on different hardware. Acer, Toshiba, Wifi drivers, Nvidia, AMD, Intel, the list goes on and on. The i5 should show the processor clock up to full speed using a monitoring tool like i7z.

Comment: How have you checked the speed? Did you use i7z? Also, if this is a laptop, is it plugged in? I had a an i3 dell laptop that would only clock to 700 something when it was unplugged or not using an official dell power adapter. However, I do think there are ways around this throttling.

Comment: You can install i7z by running the following command: `sudo apt update; sudo apt install i7z` Then, to run `i7z` just execute the following command: `sudo i7z`

Comment: It is macbook pro ,my macbook right now is working without a battery that might be the issue ?... but it doesnt make sense to downclock massively the machine performance because of the battery.. Thats why i am using ubuntu  because it gave me better performance than OS X, but is not using the machine either at its speed of 2.3 GHz... I tried CPUfreq with no luck is showing me 798MHz instead of 2.3 Ghz.